# Passing information between 2 peer components in React

Tags: reactjs

Component A is a popup dialog box with a OK button.
Component B is a text label.

A and B are both rendered from their common parent component C, but they don't call each other.

Whenever the OK button on component A is pressed, I want the text on component B to change. What kind of state passing mechanism can we use for this to happen in React?

I am not using Redux.

Comment: `C` needs to provide a method prop to `A` and a data prop to `B`, so when the action happens in `A`, the prop method is called in the parent, it will update the data prop, which will be sent to `B`.

Comment: But how can be B know the method is called ? The prop in B cannot update itself.

Comment: B expects C to send him the data prop, and when the method prop is executed from A, C will send the new data prop to B, and B doesn't need to know that the method was called, just that the data prop has been updated.

Comment: And B will re-render ?

Comment: A prop change will cause a new rendering cycle, so yes, it will re-render.

Comment: Ah i see. But what if my text as displayed in component B needs to be linked to a state inside B  (ie, i can change the text inside B's own button too)? In that case ,a prop change on B will not change its state, so the text will still not. change ?

Comment: You'll need to extract it from the state and make it a prop, and if B can update it as well (hence why you put it in the state) then you can provide the same method prop that A has to B as well. So they both update and through prop methods and it lives in the parent C.

Answer (score 2):

**component C**

- you declare a state in the common parent component

`state={
  text:''
}`

- you declare a function that takes a parameter and sets it to the state declared above

`clickHandler=(payload)=>{this.setState({text:payload})}`

- you pass the function to the component you want to get the value from

`<ComponentB  clickHandler={this.clickHandler}>`

- you pass the state to the component A

`<ComponentA text={this.state.text}>`

**component B**

- you call the function declared above in the appropriate event handler, and pass the text you want to get to the peer component as parameter

`<button onClick={()=>this.props.clickHandler('text I want to pass')}>`

**Component A**

- will receive the text as `this.props.text`

Comment: will receive the text as this.props.text. --> But props cannot change once it's sent in first. So <ComponentA text={this.state.text}> will FIX the component A's text, how will component A pick up a newly updated prop later, without refreshing the parent component C ?

Comment: If you change the state in the parent component C, it gets re-rendered along with its children, so component A will now receive the new value via it's `text` prop.